# VBscript Regular Expression in ArcMap Field Calculator

Tags: arcmap, vbscript, regular-expression

I'm looking for a regex in VBscript that I can use on a ArcMap table. I know what it would look like in python:

`pat =r'[0-9]{3,4}'`

This filters all numeric characters from the string which have the length 3 to 4. So from AO123 you'd get 123 and from VO2-324C, 324.

What would be the equivalent in VBScript? How do I implement it with the RexExp Object? ArcGIS has a Field calculator that let's you execute VBScript code. But even the most simple regex (see screenshot) fails with the error message object needed: 're'.

[image]

Comment: So.... what's the problem?  What have you tried?

Comment: see my edit on the question for more detail.

Comment: This sounds like an ArcGIS question - how to get regex to run through VBScript in ArcGIS.

Comment: You're probably right. When I posted I thought I could use the re object, just found out that ArcGIS uses the 'ATL regular expression engine' - certainly a different com object. Sorry for the confusion, I try to move my question there. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because you have not initialized the RegExp Object using `CreateObject`. I am getting results with the below script.

**Pre-Logic VBA Script Code**

```
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With re
    .Pattern = "[0-9]{3,4}"
    .Global = False
    .IgnoreCase = False
End With
targetString = [OUDE_NAAM] 'your field here
```

**Final Result Variable**

```
re.Execute(targetString).Item(0)
```

Comment: Oh, heavenly sweetness. Nice. Didn't know you have to initialize the object like this. But what do I know about VBScript? Thanks mate, man of my Monday!