# How to remove comma from combined fields which should be null?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I have Drivers License as one field and State as the other and there are to be combined and formatted as Drivers License, State.  How do I handle records that do not have either a Drivers License or State so that the field does not have a comma populated in it

Example:

> Record One: XXXXXX, ST
>
> Record Two: ,
>
> Record Three: XXXXX, ST
>
> Record Four: ,

Comment: Are you using field calculator to populate your new field?

Comment: yes, the VB script option

Answer (score 13):

You can use a regular expression.

In ArcGIS, go to the Field Calculator. For safety's sake run it on a new column.

Set to **python**.

Pre-logic script code:

```
import re
def my_regex(s):
    return re.sub("^,", "", s)
```

Name =

```
my_regex ( !Column_Name! )
```

Replace `Column_Name` with the name of the column you want to strip the , from.

[image: Field Calculator dialog]

This will strip the comma if, and only if, it is the first character in the field. It will ignore following characters. So:

`XXXXXX, ST` = unchanged

`,` becomes blank

`, ST` = becomes `ST` (including leading space)

---

To do it with VB Script (the regex will be the same): [VBscript Regular Expression in ArcMap Field Calculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31796/vbscript-regular-expression-in-arcmap-field-calculator)