# How to remove period, comma, symbols using field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, vbscript

I want to delete . , # in attribute table using field calculator (VB Script or Python).

How can I remove these using this example address: N. First St., Unit #1  (I don't need city or state name)

I checked several websites, but I couldn't find the clear answer.

[How to remove comma from combined fields which should be null?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41217/how-to-remove-comma-from-combined-fields-which-should-be-null)

http://www.geospatialanalyst.com/search/label/field%20calculator

Comment: Which field calculator are you using? ArcGIS for Desktop, QGIS and probably other GIS software have this tool.

Comment: It's ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2.1 version

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in [`str.translate(table[, deletechars])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), but with `None` for the *table* argument (requires at least Python 2.6). E.g.:

```
'N. First St., Unit #1'.translate(None, '.,#')
```

shows:

```
'N First St Unit 1'
```

Or for ArcGIS' calculator, this can be a one-liner:

```
!yourField!.translate(None, '.,#')
```

Comment: Simple, I like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Use python to calculate values in new field:

```
filter(lambda x: x not in ".,#", !yourField!)
```

Answer (score 1):

in the python code block:

```
import re

def strip(value):
    return re.sub('[.,#]','',value)
```

and then in the field calculator:

```
strip(!fieldname!)
```

Answer (score 1):

And another way.

Python Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
def remove(text):
    for char in [".", ",", "#"]:
        if char in text:
            text = text.replace(char, "")
    return str(text)
```

Bottom part:

```
remove(!yourField!)
```